# Monaco-editor syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I want to highlight the syntax in my monacho editor. I am testing with typescript/javascript. this is my index.js file:

```
import * as monaco from './node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js';

var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: 'function hello() {alert(\'Hello world!\');}',
    language: "javascript",

lineNumbers: "on",
roundedSelection: false,
scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
readOnly: false,
theme: "vs-dark",
});
```

And import these two bundle files:

```
<script type="module" src="./dist/ts.worker.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

I don't get any errors in my console, however I can't get my syntax highlighting to apply. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: what are the errors

Comment: As stated above, there are no errors. my webpack builds successfully, all files that is acquired by the electron window is successful and there is only 1 content security warning in the console because I enabled the eval() function, no other errors or anything.